# How to deserialize YAML objects into C# classes based on key name

Tags: c#, .net, yaml, deserialization, yamldotnet

I'm trying to use YamlDotNet to deserialize an array of objects into C# classes based on the key of those objects.

I have YAML like this:

```
steps:
  - launch:
      name: application
  - click:
      name: button
      repeat: 2
  - setValue:
      name: field
      value: test
```

And then some C# classes / interfaces like this:

```
public class Runner
{
    public IEnumerable<IStep> Steps { get; set; } = new List<IStep>();
}

public interface IStep
{
}

public class Launch : IStep
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class Click : IStep
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int Repeat { get; set; } = 1;
}

public class SetValue : IStep
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Using YamlDotNet, I was trying to deserialize using `WithTypeDiscriminatingNodeDeserializer` with a deserializer like this:

```
new DeserializerBuilder()
    .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
    .WithTypeDiscriminatingNodeDeserializer((options) =>
    {
        Dictionary<string, Type> keyMappings = new()
        {
            { "launch", typeof(Launch) },
            { "click", typeof(Click) },
            { "setValue", typeof(SetValue) },
        };

        options.AddUniqueKeyTypeDiscriminator<IStep>(keyMappings);
    })
    .Build();
```

But this fails with `Error: Property 'launch' not found on type 'Models.Launch'`. Based on the documentation for `AddUniqueKeyTypeDiscriminator`, this is correct behavior as those examples have properties with names equal to those keys, but I was hoping to avoid that unnecessary wrapping, how might I achieve that?